# Baby at the end True Detective season 2

Tags: plot-explanation, true-detective

In the last scene of *True Detective* episode S02E08, Jordan Semyon and detective Ani Bezzerides have a baby. Where did this baby come from? Jordan wanted a baby, did she adopt a baby? Or is this baby from detective Ray Velcoro and Ani?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The baby is the son of Bezzerides and Velcoro.

I did not watch the show till last episode, but according to wikipedia,

> In Venezuela, Bezzerides is revealed to have given birth to Velcoro's
>   second son and is living with Jordan Semyon.

Here is the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Detective_(season_2))

Answer (score 2):

[Ankit’s answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42185/1876) is correct, the baby’s parents are Bezzerides and Velcoro. This is also implied in the series:

Shortly before we see the baby for the first time, Bezzerides is talking to a journalist. She says:

> I owe his sons that.

His *sons*, not *son*. Velcoro had only one child (as far as we know), and in the course of the series he has only slept with Bezzerides (as far as we know).